# TypeScript protected and npm package

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

I'm currently building an internal TypeScript "library" with webpack 1.14.
To do so I created a npm package and published it to a private feed. Everything works like a charm (I can use classes and interfaces from the library in other "projects" installing the package).

The only thing I'm struggling with is protected members of classes in the library. **When a class in a consuming project extends a class from the library it cannot use protected parent members**. The confusing part is that auto completion "sees" the protected members but I get this error during compilation. `error TS2339: Property 'apply' does not exist on type 'SitesRollup'`

The [typescript protected keyword documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-3.html) does not state that protected members are restricted to current module, so I'm assuming it should just work.

My question is: should protected members be visible in extending/inheriting classes from different modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found where the issue was coming from. The overall type mapping wasn't working properly. This was because of two reasons:
**First** I was missing this line in the `package.json` file `"types": "dist/src/index.d.ts",` allowing tsc (and my editor) to properly locate the types of the library.
**Second** my library wasn't properly emitting the typings, fixed that adding `"declaration": true,` to my `complierOptions` in my `tsconfig.json` file.
Hope that helps.